# VB.NET: Webbrowser control unable to show local webpage properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm building an application in which the data from the database will be shown through a webbrowser control, built in html table. The purpose of using this is to allow multiple lines in the datarow and html-based formatting as well.

The webpage I have built to use in webbrowser control is working fine on a normal browser (IE, Chrome, FireFox). But it does not work when used inside webbrowser control. My webpage is using jquery, css and some script work to highlight selected rows, freeze top row, etc. This file is auto-generated by my code and is kept inside the exe directory.

Can someone guide me how to enable this webpage to be used inside webbrowser control.

The link to html files is: [source files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7288xlch3o0m025/Viewer.zip)

Thanks in advance.
Faraz.

Comment: The page works fine for me in the web browser control- that is, its displayed similarly to IE

Comment: My environment is vb.net 2010, on windows 7 64 bit. With the local internet security options set to medium-low. But its quite different from what I see on IE. For example if I click the row, it doesn't work on webbrowser control but works on IE.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. There was an incompatibility with the reset.css file in my code.